# How can I add custom row to Toolbar Title Menu ( .toolbarTitleMenu )in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want to add custom row to toolbarTitleMenu like in Apple Files App.
I want to get share folder row in first row.
[image]

I tried with a code like the one below, but I didn't get the result I wanted.

```
   .toolbarTitleMenu {
            
            Button(action: {
                
            }, label: {
                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "doc")
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("11")
                        
                        Text("11")
                    }
                }.compositingGroup()
            })
            
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "doc")
                Spacer()
                VStack{
                    Text("11")
                    
                    Text("11")
                }
            }.compositingGroup()
            
            Section{
            Text("Text Section")
            }
            
            Section{
            Label("Label Section", systemImage: "rectangle.and.pencil.and.ellipsis")
            }
        }
```

[image]

How can I customize toolbarTitleMenu row ?